# Reliable increment/decrement of cells with Javascript

Tags: google-sheets-api

I created small web page application with Javascript Google Sheets used as database for some electronic parts, where user can set/increment/decrement their amount.

My problem is I cannot find any way to simple increase-decrease by one that will be reliable with multiple users (something like Google Sheets server will handle the increment & increase requests).

My current code works this way (pseudocode):

```js
function increase_cell() {
    write_cell(read_cell() + 1);
}
```

This have the problem when I want multiple users to increment the cell at once, because if they do it in same time (read & write take about 1s so it's a pretty big window to happen), one of two increment will be lost because of rewriting of the other one.

I know its the works way to do it, but I wasn't able to find anything in the documentation and I don't know if its a feature or not. That's why I ask this question in the first place.

Comment: A system can be developed, maybe one has been, I have not researched. But standard database systems have a way for handling this situation whereas sheets does not. You can potentially write a script to protect the cell(s), write the data and then unprotect the cell(s). Database systems have a way to do this automatically behind the scenes.